# PostgreSQL invalid byte sequence for encoding utf8 0xbf

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I am importing a CSV file which is related to the properties. It has `/n` between the values. While trying to import it into a table, the following error shows up:

```
PostgreSQL invalid byte sequence for encoding utf8 0xbf
```

I tried by simply importing the single column only, but it is not working.
Column values will look like this:

```
"Job No 305385917-001: To attached Garage (Single remain).\n10305 - 132 STREET NW
Plan 23AF Blk 84 Lot 14\n2002995 LERTA LTD O/A LIR HOMES DONTON\nHENORA"
```

I want to import the above whole into a single column.

```
COPY edmonton.general_filtered (descriptive)
FROM 'D:/property_own/descriptive_details.csv'
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `COPY` statement is correct, but your data are not in UTF8 encoding.

They are probably in Latin-1 or Windows-1252, where `0xBF` is `¿`.

Specify the encoding correctly, e.g.:

```
COPY edmonton.general_filtered (descriptive)
FROM 'D:/property_own/descriptive_details.csv'
(FORMAT 'csv', HEADER, ENCODING 'WIN1252');
```

Comment: @Agnyvel your best option is to download a program (like Notepad++) where you can check the encoding of a text file.. Before using this.